Unable to create session in browser stack
I am unable to create a session in browser stack. Here is the error.
Kindly help in solving the issue.
[ERROR] [1;31mTests [0;1mrun: [0;1m2[m, [1;31mFailures: [0;1;31m1[m, Errors: 0, [1;33mSkipped: [0;1;33m1[m, Time elapsed: 6.078 s[1;31m <<< FAILURE![m - in [1mTestSuite[m
[ERROR] setUp(version_7.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 5.562 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'MAC-KCWGPMK09L', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:cc3:15fb:cc:c433%en0'
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '4.26.0', revision: '8ccf0219d7'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.7', java.version: '17.0.10'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: https://hub.browserstack.com:443
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: https://hub.browserstack.com:443
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] [1;31mFailures: [m
[ERROR] [1;31m  LoginTest>BaseTest.setUp:46 » SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session....[m

